# How to find an Item's index in a Firemonkey TListBox?

Tags: delphi, listbox, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

My goal is to update the `ItemIndex` of a `TListBox`, in a way that when programmatically adding an item to the list, the corresponding line is outlined on the `TListBox`.

I've tried:

```
with MyLstBox do begin
  ItemIndex := -1;
  for ind := 0 to Pred (Items.Count) do
    if InsertedString = Items [ind]) then begin
      ItemIndex := Ind;
      Break;
    end;
end;
```

This code outlines the item that was just inserted, but also maintains the outline of the previous inserted item.

`MultiSelect` is set to `False`, so in principle, only one item should be outlined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Items` property is a `TStrings` object.  You can use the `TStrings.IndexOf()` method instead of a manual loop:

```
MyLstBox.ItemIndex := MyLstBox.Items.IndexOf(InsertedString);
```

When you add a new item to the ListBox, the `TStrings.Add()` method returns the index of the new item:

```
MyLstBox.ItemIndex := MyLstBox.Items.Add(InsertedString);
```

Comment: OK. But there is another issue: why the previews inserted items remains highlighted?